# Inobtrusive versus unobtrusive

Tags: word-usage, differences

Is the difference in meanings between inobtrusive and unobtrusive enough to warrant a distinction in their use?  Or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that they are interchangeable and that there is little variation in their meanings. In fact, it seems that **inobtrusive** is just a *variation* of **unobtrusive**, and [many dictionaries](http://www.memidex.com/inobtrusive) cite **unobtrusive** as a definition for **inobtrusive**. According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inobtrusive%2Cunobtrusive&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinobtrusive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunobtrusive%3B%2Cc0), the variant **inobtrusive** is almost nonexistent. The spellchecker for this very editor doesn't even recognize **inobtrusive** as a word. In general, I'd stick with **unobtrusive**.

Comment: The *OED* says that they are synonymous and marks *inobtrusive* as "rare."

Answer (score 1):

They are just synonyms, *inobtrusive* being the less common variant as shown in Ngram.

[Unobtrusive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unobtrusive)

> - Not undesirably noticeable or blatant; inconspicuous.

[Inobtrusive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inobtrusive):

> - Not noticeable; unobtrusive.

(AHD)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inobtrusive%2Cunobtrusive&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinobtrusive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunobtrusive%3B%2Cc0): *unobtrusive vs inobtrusive*

[Un](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=un-&allowed_in_frame=0)-:

> - prefix of negation, Old English un-, from Proto-Germanic "un".
> - ***The most prolific of English prefixes, freely and widely used in Old English, where it forms more than 1,000 compounds***. It underwent a mass extinction in early Middle English, but emerged with renewed vigor 16c. to form compounds with native and imported words.
> - It disputes with Latin-derived cognate in- (1) the right to form the negation of certain words (indigestable/undigestable, etc.), and ***though both might be deployed in cooperation to indicate shades of meaning (unfamous/infamous), typically they are not.***

(Etymonline)

Answer (score -1):

I disagree; there is a difference.

"Inobtrusive" indicates the case for something of immediate and direct consequence (like a finger in an eye).

"Unobtrusive" works better when used to describe an element in a more sedate and benign fashion (like a car parked out of the way somewhere).

Comment: Please consider strengthening your answer by providing corroboration (in the form of dictionary definitions that support the same distinction you make in your answer) of your views from a reputable third-party source.

Comment: My reputable source is Literature and Prose and a little feeling, so its rather difficult to quantify. No doubt,readers better inclined towards academia will do a better job in this than I.
I am afraid this is a case more for art than science.
Its best approached with due respect for the nebulous, if present.